# PHP & S3: Need architecture guidance

Tags: php, architecture, amazon-s3, storage

I'm looking to provide end users of my web app the ability to drag/drop files on a PHP page within the app and have them auto upload into S3 for storage. From what I've been able to find, I would then store "pointers" to the S3 files in my database.  Could anyone point me to examples/docs or other that may better demonstrate how to architect this within my app?  I'm new to S3, so if there are any issues and/or better solutions for file storage (on the cheap) I'm all ears.

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

When users upload files to your app, your app uploads the file to S3. Your app then stores the unique S3 URL for that file in your database. If you weren't using S3 you'd do the same thing except the reference would be to a file on your local drive.

Then whenever you want to give the file to anyone, you can either: a) have your app retrieve the file from S3 and then serve it to your user or b) give the S3 URL to the user directly and they can download it from S3 themselves. Which you use will depend on your specific requirements but option (b) is generally better because it lets Amazon do all the work for the download. (b) even works if you have private files that aren't publicly available (like download puchases) because you can grant temporary access with URLs that expire.

In many cases, S3 is going to be more expensive than just using local storage. Amazon's storage pricing is competitive with retail hard drive prices. But on top of that you also pay S3 bandwidth fees which can actually get quite expensive. If you choose S3 because it's cheap, I think you're choosing it for the wrong reasons. You should choose S3 because it scales, it's fault tolerant, and you never have to think about growing the storage.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm providing my users with 10gb of storage space (ala Dropbox, or box.net), would S3still be the most viable solution, even if users aren't using that space in its entirety?

Comment: Seems to be working okay for Dropbox. S3 is nice in that regard because you only pay for the space that your users are actually using.